# Cant retrieve SPList items using javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, .net, caml

Im trying to use a javascript to search a Sharepoint list for a person with the name "John". It seems as if the query fails because I get an alert with the error: **Request failed. One or more field types are not installed properly. Go to the list settings page to delete these fields. undefined**

This suggests that the script ends up in the onQueryFailed()-method. I cant find anything wrong with the CAML and the internal column names are used.

Code from .aspx:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            function MyJavascript() {
            var siteUrl = '/sites/MySite/';
            var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
            var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('People');

            var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
            camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name="\'Name\'"/>' +
            '<Value Type=\'Text\'>John</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>');
            this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);

            clientContext.load(collListItem);
            clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));

        }

        function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {
            var listItemInfo = '';

            var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();
            while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
                var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
                listItemInfo += '\nID: ' + oListItem.get_id() +
                '\nName: ' + oListItem.get_item('Name') +
                '\nAge: ' + oListItem.get_item('Age');
            }

            alert(listItemInfo.toString());
        }

        function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
            alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
        } 

        </script>
```

Code from the .cs that registers the script to a button:

```
SubmitButton.Attributes.Add("onclick", "MyJavascript(); return false;");
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the **internal** name of the field you are querying?  Are you sure it is `Name`?

Comment: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/ is more suitable.

Comment: @Servy Yes, the internal name is Name.

Comment: Can you access the list on SharePoint using web browser and go into this list? If acceptable, please also try to change the name of `Name` field into something more unique, like `PersonName` to be sure you've not used a reserved field name.

Comment: Thanks but just solved it myself. Faulty quotation marks were present in the FieldRed-parameter.

Comment: A follow-up question, somewhat unrelated:

Can I make my submit button execute both this MyJavascript() AND execute a C#-method Submit() existing in my code behind? 

If this is not possible, maybe its possible to make the script itself submit a new item to my Sharepoint list.

Comment: Is SUbmitButton a button declared in Your aspx? If so, just make sure it has got `AutoPostBack` property set to `true` and change `return false;` into `return true;` in your javascript function.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting `ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(MyJavaScript, "sp.js");` directly below your `siteUrl` variable.